# Duplicating small file on remote Windows Server takes time

Tags: winforms, copy-paste

I have a remote server which is in the Cloud. A am connected through a permanent VPN to it. I have a network share that points on this server (W2016).

If I duplicate (copy/paste) a file on this network share that is 2Mb. It will take arround 40 secondes to accomplish. I have 100mb Fibre.

Is is normal that it takes 40 secondes ? Isn't supposed to be fast as I copy/paste on the same drive (the remote servers drive) and not event from server to my PC ?

When I copy/paste on this remote server, is the data passing through my PC as I am the on that initiated the c/p ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood why it is slow. Basically the copy/paste operation IS server-side. But my computer reads the entire file on the remote share before copying it. So if the file is 40Mb for example, well my PC has to read 40Mb in any case. So it is kind of downloading the file data and reuploading it but without storing it on my pc.